# Listing entire folder->subfolder structure of Dropbox Account (Dropbox API)

Tags: php, python-2.7, recursion, dropbox-api

I am trying to find the fastest (read best performance) way to retrieve an authorized user's dropbox folders starting at the "/" path. I'm open to using either PHP or Python.

Here's my code (PHP):

```
function db_recursive($dbxClient, $path, $folders=array(), $called=array())
    {

        $folderMetadata = $dbxClient->getMetadataWithChildren($path);
        $called[] = $path;
        foreach ($folderMetadata['contents'] as $content)
        {

            if ($content['is_dir'] == true)
            {
                if (!isset($folders[$content['path']]))
                {
                    $folders[$content['path']] = $content['path'];
                }
            }
        }

        foreach ($folders as $k => $folder)
        {
            if (in_array($k, $called))
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                db_recursive($dbxClient, $k, $folders, $called);
            }
        }
    }
```

Problems running into:
1. Tried using delta method instead of getMetadatawithChildren but took 5 minutes given around 80,000 entries (same results whether using PHP or Python)
2. With getMetadatawithChildren I'm running into maximum function level errors ( have raised it up to 300)

Does anybody have any workarounds for quickly getting at all the folders and subfolders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `/delta` is definitely the fastest way to do this. See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/69/efficiently-enumerating-dropbox-with-delta.

That said, five minutes *sounds* a bit long for 80,000 entries. I would have expected more like one to two minutes, so it might be worth investigating where that time is going (e.g. how many calls are being made and how many entries are coming back with each call).

Comment: Thanks, I've used that guide before and have translated it to PHP :)
There's no parameter in the API to return dir's only?

Comment: No, everything returns all entries (files and folders both).